# HTML 5 - frame by frame animation

Tags: html

I have a frame by frame animation that I want to recreate in HTML 5.

I have for example, one element, like a ball, for example, and keyframes like this:

```
var x = new Array(102,130,140,200);
var y = new Array(52,120,240,400);
var opacity = new Array(0,0.2,0.5,0.3); // I am assuming opacity goes from 0 to 1
```

these four positions represents x, y and opacity of the ball position on keyframes 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Each keyframe is to be called, for example, every 1/30 second. The element to be animated, the ball in this example, is a png image.

How do I animate that ball on the canvas?

I found this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #myCanvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1 / 30);
        };
      })();

      function animate() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // update stage

        // clear stage
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // render stage

        // request new frame
        requestAnimFrame(function() {
          animate();
        });
      }

      window.onload = function() {
        animate();
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

but this code does not shows how I would include an object animating there...

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to create an object representing the ball, then - from my point of view - the best practice is to add some properties like `x` and `y` coordinates, `velocity`, `mass` etc. You can define these either using object literals or by assigning each property separately. It's up to you. This way you have the base for future re-usability.

This is one of the possibilities you can build up your code. I slightly modified the original one by separating the rendering function from the initialization. This is only for optimization concernings.

```
function Ball(ctx, x, y, rad) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.rad = rad;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
    this.mass = 0;

    this.createBall = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#rgba(38,85,139,1)';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 2*Math.PI, false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();        
    };

    this.update = function() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        if (this.x > canvas.width) {
            this.x = canvas.width - 1;
            this.vx *= -1;
        }            
        //...        
    };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function init() {    
    var numBalls = 100;
    var ballPool = [];
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;
    var ball = new Ball(context, Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height,
                        (Math.random() * 10 - 5) + 2);

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        ballPool.push(ball);        
      }
}

function animate() {
    var len = ballPool.length;
    var ball = null;

    for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
        ball = Ball(ballPool[i]);
        ball.update();
    }
}

window.onload = init();     
requestAnimFrame(animate);
```

**Note**

I didn't tested the code, i make it only to got the idea. One side-note: i didn't constructed my code to use keyframes, but it's possible to use keyframes too, only you need a big pool of coordinates for a smoother transition.

Comment: thanks. I will analyze your code. I really need it reading a pool of coordinates and the element, like the ball, is a png image. Anyway thanks!!!!

Comment: ...then you only have to assign the ball's coordinates to the keyframes positions by iterating through the array. The trick is to assign the ball `x` and `y` position to the new coordinates on each redraw. For this purpose you may use a counter which serves as the index for the array pointer and on each redraw you increase this value with one. Hope this helps.